# Expressing a vector as a linear combination of orthonormal basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

I have a vector:

$w$ = $(1, 1)$

That I need to express as a linear combination of orthonormal basis vectors:

$u$ = $(\frac{1}{\sqrt5},\frac{3}{\sqrt5})$ and $v$ = $(\frac{2}{\sqrt5},\frac{1}{\sqrt5})$, which have been normalised from $u$ = $(1, 3)$ and $v$ = $(2, 1)$.

Note: I am using the inner product of:

$(u, v)$ = $2$$v_1$$u_1$ - $v_1$$u_2$ - $v_2$$u_1$ + $v_2$$u_2$

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate someone telling me what I could do to improve upon this question rather than just closing it or voting it down. Thank you.

Comment: Your $u$ and $v$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: They are when substituted into the inner product of 2$v_1$$u_1$ - $v_1$$u_2$ - $v_2$$u_1$ + $v_2$$u_2$.

Comment: You did not mention that you are not using the standard inner product. You should edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @Bungo I've just edited the question.

Comment: Surely the whole point of orthonormal bases $e_i$ is that the $i$-coefficient for a vector $w$ is $\langle w,e_i\rangle$?

Comment: Btw, you have not normalized $u$ correctly with respect to the norm induced by your nonstandard inner product. Your un-normalized $u$ satisfies $\|u\|^2 = \langle  u,u \rangle = 2 - 3 - 3 + 9 = 5$, so you need to divide it by $\|u\| = \sqrt{5}$, not $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally wrote them the other way around.

Comment: @Bungo If it is $\sqrt5$, it then becomes $(\frac{1}{\sqrt5},\frac{3}{\sqrt5})$, which if I try to find the magnitude of, will give me $\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} + \frac{9}{5}}$, which = $\sqrt2$, not 1.

Comment: @Broadsword93 You are not computing the magnitude correctly. The magnitude of $u$ is not simply $\sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2}$, because you are not using the standard inner product. Instead, you have to compute $\|u\| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} = \sqrt{2u_1^2 - u_1 u_2 - u_2 u_1 + u_2^2}$.

Comment: Ah, right. Got you now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You seek coefficients $a$ and $b$ such that $au + bv = w$. If we express $u$, $v$, and $w$ as column vectors, and define the matrix $A = [u | v]$ whose columns are $u$ and $v$, then $au + bv$ can be written as
$$A\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$$
You want this equal to $w$, so
$$A\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = w$$
If we multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$, we obtain the desired coefficients:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = A^{-1}w$$

This is particularly easy for orthonormal $u$ and $v$, for in that case we have $A^{-1} = A^t$. However, as noted in the comments, your $u$ and $v$ are not orthogonal, hence not orthonormal, assuming the standard inner product.

---

Another approach is to start with
$$au + bv = w$$
and take the inner product of both sides with $u$ and with $v$. Assuming $u$ and $v$ are orthonormal, taking the inner product of both sides with $u$ gives us
$$a\langle u,u\rangle + b\langle v,u \rangle = \langle w,u \rangle$$
which simplifies to
$$a = \langle w,u \rangle$$
since $\langle u,u\rangle = 1$ and $\langle v,u \rangle = 0$.

Similarly, taking the inner product of both sides of $au + bv = w$ with $v$ gives us
$$b = \langle w, v \rangle$$

---

Note that the first technique works even if $u$ and $v$ are not orthonormal, but requires inverting a matrix. The second technique is computationally easier but requires orthonormality of $u$ and $v$.

Since you are using a nonstandard inner product, you will not have $A^{-1} = A^t$ in the first method. So the second method will be easier, but be sure to use your inner product and not the standard one.

---

Applying method 1 to your situation, we have
$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
so 
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 \\ 3 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
and therefore 
$$\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore
$$a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
and
$$b = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$

---

Applying method 2 to your situation, we have
$$\begin{aligned} a &= \langle w, u\rangle \\
&= 2u_1 w_1 - u_1 w_2 - u_2 w_1 + u_2 w_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (2(1 \cdot 1) - 1\cdot 1 - 3\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{aligned}$$
and 
$$\begin{aligned} b &= \langle w, v\rangle \\
&= 2v_1 w_1 - v_1 w_2 - v_2 w_1 + v_2 w_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (2(2 \cdot 1) - 2\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1) \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Am I using the normalised vectors of $u$ and $v$?

Comment: @Broadsword93 Yes, the second method only works if $u$ and $v$ are orthonormal (normalized and orthogonal). We explicitly used $\langle u,u \rangle = 1$ and $\langle v,v \rangle = 1$ in the computation of $a$ and $b$. As mentioned in my earlier comment to your question, be sure to compute the magnitude as $\|u\| = \sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$, *not* as $\langle u \rangle = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2}$. (And similarly for $v$.)

Comment: The first method will work for any linearly independent $u$ and $v$, regardless of whether they are orthonormal. But it requires more work.

Comment: Is this correct? https://i.imgur.com/hbQdvLe.jpg

Comment: @Broadsword93 Looks right to me!

Comment: Really? I thought it may have been incorrect. This was my other attempt: https://imgur.com/a/H6v8qCX Is that still right?

Comment: @Broadsword93 I added two sections at the end showing explicit calculations for both methods. The answers are consistent with your "is this correct?" attempt above: $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $b = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: In your second attempt, you appear to be using the standard inner product, instead of the one defined in your question.